# Is there a list of the cards included in Scuttle! and its expansions?

Tags: components

So I have the card game Scuttle! and two of its expansion sets: Scurvy and Curse of the Black Jack.

Stupidly, I shuffled all the cards together and now I want to separate them out again.

Luckily, 'the Scurvy' cards are pretty easy to find as they're very distinct. Now I'm just trying to separate the cards from the base Scuttle! deck and the Curse of the Black Jack cards.

Is there a list of the cards anywhere? I checked the jellybeans games website and there's nothing there. Help me please! Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome. I edited your question with paragraphs so it can be read easily. Hope you find a good answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would expect a game inventory on the Jelly Bean website.

Took a little search, but here’s a [YouTube](https://youtu.be/KOcIzwBE0j4) that reviews the Black Jack game expansion, showing all of those cards. They are:

Black Jack rule card, Voodoo Queen, Governor, Dagger, Powder Keg, Sea Serpent, Black Jack, Ghost Pirate, Grappling Hook, Black Spot, Crow’s Nest, Grog, Buried Treasure, Sirens, The Plank, Poison, and Parrot.

That should allow you to finish splitting up your decks.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I should've looked to YouTube first!

Comment: @fiend Glad that helped.  =)